# Como separar uma string de um arquivo que contêm uma sequência de rodadas de xadrez?

Tags: c, arquivo, caracteres

Preciso ler um arquivo que vai estar codificado como o exemplo:

`1.e4 e6 2.Nf3 d5 3.Nc3 Nf6 4.e5 Nfd7 5.d4 b6 6.Bd3 Ba6 7.O-O Be7 8.Ne2 Bxd3 9.Qxd3 c5 10.c4 Nc6 11.cxd5 Nb4 12.Qe4 Nxd5 13.Qg4 Kf8 14.Nf4 Nxf4 15.Bxf4 h5 16.Qg3 cxd4 17.Rfd1 Rc8 18.Rxd4 Rc7 19.Rad1 h4 20.Qg4 h3 21.Ng5 Bxg5 22.Bxg5 Qe8 23.R4d3 f6 24.exf6 gxf6 25.Bf4 f5 26.Rxh3 Rxh3 27.Bd6+ Kf7 28.Qxh3 Rc8 29.Qh7+ Kf6 30.Bg3 Rc4 31.Bh4+ 1-0`

Trata-se de uma sequência de rodadas de xadrez com os devidos movimentos realizados pelas peças brancas e pretas, respectivamente, sendo as rodadas separadas pelos números "1.... 2.... 3.... etc".
No caso, preciso ler o arquivo, armazenar o movimento realizado, validar, e, caso esteja correto, partir para o próximo movimento, senão encerro meu programa. Obs a rodada toda está escrita em uma única linha.

Minha dúvida é como construo o algoritmo para ler cada movimento por vez armazenando o mesmo em um vetor de caracteres. O código está sendo escrito em C.

Solução encontrada:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TAM 10

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char branca[TAM], preta[TAM];
    int junk;

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    memset(branca, 0x0, TAM);
    memset(preta, 0x0, TAM);

    while(fscanf(f, "%d.%s %s", &junk, branca, preta) && !feof(f)){

        printf("BRANCA: %s\n", branca);
        printf("PRETA: %s\n", preta);
        printf("---------------\n");

    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: O número da rodada sempre estará seguido do caractere '.' (ponto)? Cada sequencia de caracteres que identifica um movimento estará seguida do caractere ' ' (espaço)?

Comment: sim! 1.e4(movimento da peça branca) e6(movimento da peça preta) 2.Nf3(mov. branca) d5(mov. preta) etc

Comment: Então tente com: `fscanf(, arquivo, "%d.%s %s", &rodada[i], mov_branca[i], mov_preta[i]);`  até detectar EOF. Agora eu não tenho ideia do que seja "validar o movimento". Talvez você não precise do vetor de rodada, o próprio valor i+1 fornecerá a rodada.

Comment: ah, isso! como eu preciso só de um vetor por vez, vou usar o que você disse dessa forma: while(fscanf(f, "%d.%s %s", &junk, branca, preta) && !feof(f)){... 
Sobre o validador, é uma parte do trabalho que pede para validar se cada jogada do arquivo está correta, ou seja, se determinada peça realizou o movimento corretamente. Se o movimento lido estiver errado segundo as regras de cada peça, o programa encerra. Se o movimento estiver correto, eu passo para o próximo. Por isso eu preciso apenas de um movimento por vez. Muito obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite.

Bom, aqui está uma das formas de fazer, também existem outras...

No exemplo abaixo, a leitura é feita caractere por caractere e todos os dados do arquivo serão impressos na tela. Nesse exemplo, eu mostro uma rodada por linha; para identificar sua separação, escrevo um '\n' a cada dois caracteres de espaços lidos.

Para a sua necessidade,' basta escrever as letras num ponteiro usando alocação dinâmica, em vez de imprimi-las na tela.
Se você quiser separar os comandos por **jogada** em vez de **rodada**, basta remover  o *if* na linha 20.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* jogo;

    printf("Mostrando movimentos...\n");

    jogo = fopen("jogo.txt", "r");

    char c = fgetc(jogo);
    int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        if (c == ' ')
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 2 == 0) // Quebra linha a cada 2 espaços em branco
                printf("\n");
        }

        printf("%c", c);
        c = fgetc(jogo);
    } while (c != EOF);


    fclose(jogo);
    return 0;
}
```

Sobre alocação dinâmica, caso necessário, você pode encontrar mais informações aqui:
https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/algoritmos/aulas/aloca.html

Comment: Sim! Consegui fazer de outra maneira, mas não estou conseguindo colocar o código aqui no comentário (iniciante). Muito obrigada!